# php function that counts number of similar characters in a string

Tags: php, string

Is there a php function that counts the number of similar characters in a string?

I've looked at levenshtein, similar_text, and metaphone none seem to do this.

Example in/output would be:
Hello, Heil outputs 3 (h, e, l)

Comment: You may want to define what "similar characters" are exactly.

Comment: updated; similar as in same

Comment: In MDN ( sorry, javascript ) it would be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Example:_Using_indexOf_to_count_occurrences_of_a_letter_in_a_string.

Comment: `array_count_values(str_split($myOriginalString,1));`

Comment: So you want to find the characters that two strings have **in common**? Or that **occur more than once**?

Comment: @deceze letters that are common between the two

Comment: Then the answer you accepted below does not match the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_split` to convert the strings into arrays, then `array_unique` and `array_intersect` to get the common letters.

For example:

```
$str1 = "hello";
$str2 = "hola";

$chars1 = array_unique(str_split($str1));
$chars2 = array_unique(str_split($str2));

echo "Common characters: ".count(array_intersect($chars1, $chars2));
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to also count non-unique answers as in "e,a" in your example?

Answer (score 4):

Use count_chars

Example

```
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";

foreach (count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of \"" , chr($i) , "\" in the string.\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php